# Using jQuery to text-align child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this element

```
<p class="msg-item"></p>
```

That is dynamically filled with

Either

```
<span class="you"></span>
```

Or

```
<span class="stranger"></span>
```

I'm trying to get jQuery to **text-align** the `<span class="you"></span>` elements to the right.

So, I'm trying with this code:

```
if($('p.msg-item').find('span.you').length != 0){
    $("p.msg-item.span.you").css('text-align','right');
}
```

but it's not working, any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: can you provide more code ? , or create a fiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is the selector, If you don't use a space then it goes to find the element with 3 classes `class="msg-item span you"`. Which in your case is not there.

change to this:

```
$("p.msg-item span.you")
```

Better to do this with css only:

```
p.msg-item span.you{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`span.you` is a children of `p.msg-item`. That comes like

```
$("p.msg-item span.you").css('text-align','right');
```